# Solving system of inequalities, with solution in only natural numbers, with priority on variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, natural-numbers

If I have the equations

$27a+30b+33c+36c \geq x$

$a+b+c+d=4$

and want to solve them using only natural numbers (including 0) for both

$x=131 $ and $x=142 $

preferably but not necessarily with

$a\geq b\geq c\geq d$

How do I approach this. Can I use linear algebra? Do I just use algebra? Theres two knowns and four unknowns, but with the extra restrictions there should be a limited number of solutions. Using just algebra I get stuck after reducing like in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194363/solving-a-system-of-equations-with-natural-numbers) question:

$27(a+b+c+d)+3b+6c+9d \geq 131$

$108+3b+6c+9d \geq 131$

$3b+6c+9d \geq 23$

here it gets messy with wanting only natural numbers, I would like to divide by 3 but then probably my results wont be in natural numbers. Can I continue like this having to use real numbers and then later return to natural numbers? Then I get

$b+2c+3d \geq 7+2/3$

Three unknowns, dont know how to continue, there must be many solutions but Im not sure how to find them. Maybe $a+b+c+d=4$ and only natural numbers is so restricting I should just calculate all possible combinations and see which solve the inequality? Then how to calculate all possible combinations?

Comment: Perhaps an extension of Bresenham's Line Algorithm would be your best bet.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: From your equation $b+2c+3d\ge 7+\frac 23,$ we know that the left side is an integer, and it is at least $7+\frac 23,$ so it has to be at least $8$. So you get $b+2c+3d\ge 8$. It's better to look at it as $4\ge 3a+2b+c$, because then this forces $a=0$ or $a=1$. The rest can be completed by checking cases.